# Debugging Node.js with Typescript using Webpack in VSCode is impossible, please some advice

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code

I expend almost 6 hours trying to make this work but it seems it refuses by all methods.
I made a simple API with NodeJS using Typescript and Webpack, but when I tried to debug it put break points and all of that  stuff, VSCode put it very difficult.

**Launch.json :**

```
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "type": "node",
           "request": "launch",
           "name": "Launch Program",
           "preLaunchTask": "npm: start - server",
           "skipFiles": [
               "<node_internals>/**"
           ],
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\server\\webpack.config.ts",
           "outFiles": [
               "${workspaceFolder}/server/dist/index.js"
           ],
           "sourceMaps": true,
           "trace": true
       }
   ]
}
```

**webpack.config.ts :**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.ts"],
  devtool: "source-map",
  watch: true,
  target: "node",
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      allowlist: ["webpack/hot/poll?100"]
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  mode: "development",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js"
  }
};
```

**index.ts of my app which uses middleware with routers to redirect url requests.**

```
    import express from "express";
    import cors from "cors";
    import helmet from "helmet";
    import { categoryRouter } from "./routers/category.router";
    import { CategoryPostgre } from "./database/postgre/category.postgre";

    dotenv.config();

/**
 * App Variables
 */

    if (!process.env.PORT) {
        process.exit(1);
    }
    
    const PORT: number = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10);
    
    const app = express();
    const router = express.Router();

/**
 *  App Configuration
 */

    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());

    /**
    *  Service Initialization
    */
    console.log(`Inicializando Servicios`);

    app.use('/api/category', categoryRouter);


/**
 * Server Activation
 */
       
    const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`----------------------------------------------------------------`);
        console.log(`--- App V 0.1 NodeJS Server Listening on port ${PORT} ---`);
        console.log(`----------------------------------------------------------------`);
```

**tsconfig.json :**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */                         /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

I want just the debugger to stay listening to break points, so when I trigger a request using postman, it stops on my **categoryRouter** function and I can see what's going on right there.

Now it just do nothing when I run it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are 2 types of request when configuring a `launch.json` :

- `launch`: which will launch a new server on its own.
- `attach`: which tells to vscode whenver you press the start debug button, to attach the debbuger to an existing running process.

The first option is mostly used for when you want to debbug a script in the sense of, it can run on its own and it does not expect external input.

Second one can be used if you have your server already running on whatever port you have specified.

Try the following:
`package.json`:

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack",
      "start": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 lib/index.js",
      ...
   }
}
```

**Note** lib/index.js is my compiled file, as I'm using ts in my project.
`--inspect=...:9229` tells the running server to listen for a client connection (debugger) on the specified port.
if your server is running inside docker leave the host address to: `0.0.0.0` but if you're not using it, set it to: `127.0.0.1`

Then you need to configure your `.vscode/launch.json` so that it can connect to the server.
this is the config I'm using:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "restart": true,
            "port": 9229,
            "address": "localhost",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/application",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note** `/application` is the `WORKDIR` I have defined in my `Dockerfile`
if you're not using docker, you probably don't need this property.

With this set up, I can have docker running my server, and at any point I need to debug an endpoint in my server, I can simply run the debugger from vscode, and add a breakpoint in my source code, then from postman when I trigger a request, vscode will pause the execution at the breaking point.

Good luck, hope this helps. :)